# How to use OData $orderby on child array of string

Tags: c#, odata

My returning Object from back end is `IQueryable<Article>` and `Article` has a collection of `tags` which is `IEnumerable<string>`

for example

```
[
  {
    id: 'Article 1'
    tags : [{'t1','t2','t3'}]
  },
  {
    id: 'Article 2'
    tags : [{'t5','t6','t1'}]
  },
]
```

I can filter records by Odata query as below

```
http://localhost:52475/api/articles?$select=id,tags&$filter=tags/any(item: substringof('j',item) eq true)
```

Now I want to sort this by `$orderBy`
I tried below but no chance

```
http://localhost:52475/api/articles?$select=id,tags&$orderby=tags(item: item)

http://localhost:52475/api/articles?$select=id,tags&$orderby=tags

http://localhost:52475/api/articles?$select=id,tags&$orderby=tags/

http://localhost:52475/api/articles?$select=id,tags&$orderby=tags(item)
```

I know that if tags collection has another property called name I could use this

```
http://localhost:52475/api/articles?$select=id,tags&$orderby=tags/name
```

But it doesn't have , and also I am not able to change backend

Comment: I have the same issue. And this question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548165/in-odata-is-there-a-way-to-order-by-the-first-element-in-an-array). Any help?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for it