# OData sort by value in a collection

Tags: c#, sorting, sql-order-by, odata

I have the following classes:

```
public class Product {
    int Id;
    string Slug;
    ICollection<Price> Prices;
}


public class Price {
    int Id;
    float Amount;
    PriceType Type;
}

public class PriceType {
    int Id;
    string Name;
    bool isPublic;
}
```

I have an **OData API** that returns a list of products.

**I want to get products ordered by the value "amount" of "Prices" using only a specific PriceType (name="final"), so the collection "Prices" comes always with one child.**

*For example* the response could be:

```json
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Slug: "432433",
        Prices: [{Id:1, Amount: 1000, type:"final"}]
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Slug: "542131",
        Prices: [{Id:1, Amount: 800, type:"final"}]
    }
]
```

***The problem is that I'm not able to use the $orderby clause*** in the OData query because the attribute Price comes as an array.

Below an example query used to get products:

```
http://{URL_API}/products/?
    skip=0&
    top=12&
    expand=prices(filter=(PriceType/Name eq 'final'))&
    select=id,slug,prices&
    orderby=prices
```

which returns:

```json
"error": 
{
    "code": "",
    "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The $orderby expression must evaluate to a single value of primitive type.",
}
```

Is there a way to sort results somehow? Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444708/how-to-use-odata-orderby-on-child-array-of-string, which also does not have an accepted answer unfortunately.